# Backendless - Deleting Data Objects by ID

Tags: android, android-intent, hashmap, backendless

I am trying to delete an Object of my Table Books with Backendless by its objectId. Reffering to the Backendless Documentation I tried the following code in my BookDetailActivity:

```
//inside onCreate
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteBook();
        }
    });

//outside onCreate
public void deleteBook()
{
    HashMap book = new HashMap();
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String object_id = b.getString("objectId");
    book.put( "ObjectId", object_id );
    Backendless.Persistence.of( "Books" ).remove( book, new AsyncCallback<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(Long aLong) {
        }
        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
        }
        });
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "book deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, BooksListActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

The Id of the selected book is correct, but the complete Object (book with author, releasedate, description,...) won't be deleted. Where is the problem? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you have created `HashMap` book but with no values added to, are you missing something? maybe adding `book.put("book_id",object_id );` ?

Comment: also add some logs to `handleResponse()` and `handleFault()`

Comment: Sorry, I missed one line while copying, but the problem is still the same!

Comment: I fixed it, it was a typing error... I used "ObjectId" instead of "objectId".

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already solved it, but still I'll leave this answer for the others who may run into the same problem.

In order to delete some object, it should have an `objectId` field (either as a class property or a field in a Map). The field name should be exactly the same, in the same case. Your concrete problem is caused by the first letter being uppercase - it should be lowercase.

By the way, if you added some logs into `handleFault()`, you would see the following error in `BackendlessFault.getMessage()`:

> Unable to remove object. Object with the specified primary key does
>   not exist

Basically, this is the error you get when either there is no object with the specified `objectId` or there is no `objectId` property in the request at all. Your case would be the second one.